# Android LinearGradient color interpolator doesn't work on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, gradient, samsung-mobile, linear-gradients

I've implemented a vertical `LinearGradient` for a custom `View`. It is working good on most of devices but we've noticed that on a Galaxy Note 2, running Android 4.1.2, the gradient is not transitioning smoothly between colors (color interpolation), but each color just starts at some point.

I'm constructing the gradient like this

```
    ViewCompat.setLayerPaint(myView, null);
    Paint paint = myView.getPaintRender();
    paint.setDither(true);

    int height = myView.getHeight();

    // create a gradient background paint which will be later on clipped
    mColors = generateColorsRage(myDTOProvidingData);
    float[] percentages = generateColorPercentages();

    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, mColors, percentages, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    paint.setShader(linearGradient);
```

Can somebody point me to a direction?

Thanks!

Comment: what are `mColors` & `percentages`? did you try to `Log.d` them out?

Comment: `mColors` is an array of int[[] containing the color codes for gradient steps. The `percentages` and floating values in [0..1] for the actual color change steps. And yes, I've logged them out and they look just fine

Comment: also is `height` != 0?, try just for testing `new LinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);` followed by `paint.setShader` and `canvas.drawPaint`

Comment: @pskink the height is greater than 0. The same algorithm is working perfect on all other versions, except for Android 4.1.2. Also I'm using the other constructor for `LinearGradient`, the one with percentages array

Comment: did you try above code? also did you try turning off hardware acceleration?

Comment: Yes and it's working but I do not need that. I need multiple colors (dynamically determined) with different distribution (not always equal distribution).

Comment: post the content of `int colors[]` and `float positions[]`, just to be sure, did you try turning off hrdw-accel?

Comment: @pskink yes i've tried to turn off hardware acceleration, and to set Software layer rendering to the view, turning on dithering .. nothing works

Comment: so what are `float positions[]`? some floats between [0..1] each one greater then previous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally come to a solution.
It seems that the `LinearGradient` class on the Android 4.1.2 has a weird way of handling percentages.
It seems that the colors interpolations are not working if the percentages do not have at least one value equals to `1f`.

So to fix this, I made sure that the `percentages[]` have the last value set to `1f` and both `mColors[]` and `percentages[]` are the same length in order for this to properly work.